# python GtkComboBox.remove_all(): how to prevent changed signal to be triggered

Tags: python, gtk3

I have designed a gtk3 layout with Glade, including some comboboxtext widgets.

The `bookings_tour_selector` ComboBoxText has the `changed` signal connected, so when user selects an option, this is detected. That part works fine.

Now the problem, when I make the call: `bookings_tour_selector.remove_all()` the `changed` signal is triggered once for every single item being removed. That's not the expected behaviour. I expect it to not trigger the signal at all.

How to prevent this signal to be triggered when removing items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add conditional in your callback, i.e:

```
def on_changed_combobox (self, widget):
    if self.bookings_tour_selector.get_active () != -1:
        #do whatever you want when combo box changed
        #if not, it simply, does nothing
```

Comment: Simple and effective :) Thanks